# Entity Framework Raw SQL with relational entities

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I recently started experimenting with Raw SQL using Entity Framework, and I prefer it in some cases.
I would like to know if there is a way to grab relational entities:

Dosnt work:

```
var personNo = context.Person.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM `Person` LIMIT 1").FirstOrDefault();

foreach(var Number in personNo.Phone) {
  //never iterates
}
```

Works (but LINQ-to-Entities which I dont want in this case):

```
var personNo = context.Person.FirstOrDefault();

foreach(var Number in personNo.Phone) {
  //iterate twice as it contains in the db
}
```

I tried a couple of different queries including

```
SELECT * FROM `Person` LEFT JOIN `Phone` ON (`Person`.ID = `Phone`.PersonID) LIMIT 1
```

What is the correct way to write the query on to recieve the list of Phone numbers? Is this possible?

Comment: This might be a detail, but shouldn't you write `\`Person\`` instead of `\`Person \`` in your native query ?

Comment: Very noticed! Thanks, it was a mistake when copy-pasting though

Answer (score 0):

You can do SQL to entities. I prefer this way when I have joins and group bys in them, and don't have permission to create a view.

First, create a class and add properties with the same names as the returned columns.

```
public class PersonWithAddress
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Address { get; set; }
}
```

And the C# with parameters

```
MyEntity db = new MyEntity();
String sqlQuery = @"
  SELECT Id, Name, Address
  FROM Person p
  JOIN Address a
  ON a.Id = p.Id
  WHERE Name = @Name
  AND Address = @Address
";
String searchName = "Joe";
String address = "123 Something Lane";

DbRawSqlQuery<PersonWithAddress> results = db.Database.SqlQuery<PersonWithAddress>(
    sqlQuery,
    new SqlParameter("@Name", searchName),
    new SqlParameter("@Address", address)
);

foreach(PersonWithAddress a in results)
{

}
```

You can list as many parameters as you want.
Wow this question's 2 years old. I didn't even realize that.